# grails asset pipeline is not showing expected behavior

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

we are currently working on grails 2.4.3 and using asset pipeline 1.9.6.

in 'dev' / development mode, the plugin is not supposed bundle css and js files/assets. but we see the behavior where it bundles anyway. its making our development work a lot harder.

we have setting `grails.assets.minifyJs = false` in config.groovy
even tried `grails.assets.bundle=false`. not helping.
not sure what else is missing.

any suggestions ?

Comment: Does it actually mash all your assets into a single file or just serves them as individual files as they are defined in the bundle?

Comment: it just puts them all together into one file. so debugging is a pain